# Alternative to Poisson process with non-independent events?

Tags: modeling, poisson-distribution, independence, poisson-process

Correct me if I'm wrong but as far I know, a Poisson distribution assumes the events are independent of each other. I have a dataset of events over several years where the occurrence of an event may drive/encourage the occurrence of the next few events (possibly, can't say for sure, some of these events may occur independently as well). I want to find the probability of exactly two events happening within a 3-month period. What is the best way to find that?

I'm also concerned that the event rates were probably quite different at different years, forming something similar to a nonhomogeneous Poisson process, in case we can consider the process as Poisson at all!

Comment: So you say events may occur in clusters? Please give some more context!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes, the events may occur in clusters. We are looking at crime data. We have dates of these crime events and we believe sometimes these events can encourage other criminals to conduct similar crimes. But that is only an assumption we have. Not sure if that really happens. But from the exploration, it seems like that could be the case.